# SQL order by col a then col b but display all same col b of same value together

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have a query that I am trying to order by in a particular way, and hoping there is a way to do this where I can avoid subqueries.

The SQL looks something like this.

```
SELECT 
  CustomerID,
  count(*) as itemsPurchased,
  dayPurchased
  locationPurchased
FROM orders
WHERE dayPurchased > @startDate AND dayPurchased < @endDate
GROUP BY CustomerID, locationPurchased, dayPurchased
ORDER BY itemsPurchased desc, CustomerID
```

This sorts the data with example data like such

```
CustomerID itemsPurchased  dayPurchased  locationPurchased
5          20              day1          loc1
2          10              day1          loc1
5          5               day1          loc2
```

I would like it sorted in such a way that it shows the customer with the most items purchased then all their other purchases, it then moves to the next customer. ex.

```
CustomerID itemsPurchased  dayPurchased  locationPurchased
5          20              day1          loc1
5          5               day1          loc2
2          10              day1          loc1
```

Thanks!

Comment: try ORDER BY CUSTOMER_ID, itemsPurchased DESC

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server? Please only tag one RDBMS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a window function in the `ORDER BY` to get the maximum number of purchases:

```
ORDER BY MAX(COUNT(*)) OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerID) DESC,
         CustomerID,
         itemsPurchased desc
```

I am not sure if you want the maximum for a given item or the total number of items.  If the latter, use `SUM()` instead of `MAX()`.